Cefsharp (Libcef.dll) program crashes after opening web page from WPF
I am having an issue with using CefSharp to open a web page from a WPF application.
<Grid>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Address="about:blank" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Width="Auto"
                         Height="Auto"/>
</Grid>

public void Navigate(string url)
{
    browser.Address = url;
}

BrowserWindows browserWindows = new BrowserWindows();
browserWindows.Navigate(url);
browserWindows.Closed += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (OnWindowClosed != null)
        {
            OnWindowClosed(1, true, _paramString, _idperson);
        }
    };
    browserWindows.Show();

In WPF, I open a window, and in that window, I use ChromiumWebBrowser (CefSharp) to navigate to a web page. When I run it in the Debug environment, there are no issues, and everything runs smoothly. However, when I build the application and run it in the production environment, the program crashes a few seconds after the website screen is displayed. Checking the Windows Event log, I get the following result:
Faulting application name: Test.exe, version: 6.0.0.135, time stamp: 0x6707d47d
Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 129.0.11.0, time stamp: 0x66fb0c5a
Exception code: 0x4000001f
Error offset: 0x04ea8352
Faulting process ID: 0x0x391C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DB1BBC15CD5A5C
Faulting application path: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test\\Test.exe
Faulting module path: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test\\libcef.dll
Report identifier: a1c6a7fb-e83b-4853-b6cc-a1c05b13494c
Full name of the faulting package:
Application ID relative to the faulting package:

I have tried building the program as x64, but the error still occurs.

Enable logging in CEF and run the app in a terminal. Exception code: 0x4000001f means some CHECK in CEF failed. The enabled logging will describe the failure.

Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4954 please just ask your question once.
